# Java compiler command concept is eluding my grasp

Tags: vim, javacompiler

OK, so the problem that I am having is that whenever I type javac into the cmd prompt, it doesn't compile the file I specified. I have a couple if question to help my understanding of what it actually does.

-can you compile jar files? If so, what will it do.

-if you type a basic hello world program in a text editor, such as vim, what do you save it as? Hello world . class, hello world.java, hello world.txt?

-if you have a text file, class file, or Java file correctly formatted, how do you compile it CORRECTLY?

-do you have to specify a class or file in your program? (public class example{})

-how is vim really that different than cmd prompt?

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be going through your questions one at a time:

1. It doesn't make sense to compile `.jar` files... You can only run them.
2. Save it as `HelloWorld.java`, and `HelloWorld.class` will be created once you compile it. *Avoid using spaces in file names as much as possible, it will make things easier.*
3. First navigate to the source folder which contains the file using `cd` commands, then type `javac ExampleProject.java`. Obviously you would replace "ExampleProject" with the correct name.
4. If you want to do something meaningful, then you have to declare a class. I don't think a file with only import statements would do much good :P
5. VIM is a text editor for writing your code; Command Prompt is used for the computer's administrative functions and executing batch files.

Let me know if you need additional clarification.

Comment: So does it matter what class you declare in the program? Does it have to be the same as the file name?

Comment: A java file can contain one public class, and its name should be the same as the file's. [Here's some info.](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2011/01/javas-file-names-and-class-names.html)

Comment: @Peter_Browning Do you still need any help?

Comment: Actually yes, there is a program out there called git bash. I am not sure exactly as to what this is supposed to do, or what it can do, but any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Git is a popular version control system, and Git Bash is a shell program where `git` is a known command. If you would like to get a more detailed response from the community, please accept this answer with the check mark and ask a new question.